# compute similarities in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm busy making filters. Now I want to compare 5 arrays which contain objects. In a computed variable I only want to have the objects that are found in all the arrays.

These are the computed variables that create the different filters (which are arrays that contain objects)

```
computed: 
    filteredOnColor () {
      this.presentOnColor = []
      for (var p = 0; p < this.paintings.length; p++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.kleur.length; i++) {
          if (this.kleur.length > 0 && this.paintings[p].kleur.includes(this.kleur[i])) {
            this.presentOnColor.push(this.paintings[p].title)
          }
        }
      }
    },
    filteredOnTechnique () {
      this.presentOnTechnique = []
      for (var p = 0; p < this.technique.length; p++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.technique.length; i++) {
          if (this.technique.length > 0 && this.paintings[p].technique.includes(this.technique[i])) {
            this.presentOnTechnique.push(this.paintings[p].title)
          }
        }
      }
    },
    filteredOnStyle () {
      this.presentOnStyle = []
      for (var p = 0; p < this.style.length; p++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.style.length; i++) {
          if (this.style.length > 0 && this.paintings[p].style.includes(this.style[i])) {
            this.presentOnStyle.push(this.paintings[p].title)
          }
        }
      }
    },

RAW DATA

presentOnColor: [A,B,C]
presentOnStyle: [B,C,D
presentOnTechnique: [B,C,F]

presentFilter: [B,C]
```

Comment: please add the raw data and the wanted result after filtering.

Comment: I added my raw data. presentFilter is what I want to have.

Comment: computed properties are meant to return a value. Why are you setting a different data property in each computed property's method? Since those methods are only called when the computed property is accessed, your data properties probably aren't getting set how you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the arrays if the objects are included in all arrays and filter the arrays by using the common part.

```js
var $scope = { presentOnColor: ['A', 'B', 'C'], presentOnStyle: ['B', 'C', 'D'], presentOnTechnique: ['B', 'C', 'F'] },
    presentFilter = [$scope.presentOnColor, $scope.presentOnStyle, $scope.presentOnTechnique].reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a.filter(function(c) {
            return b.indexOf(c) !== -1;
        });
    });

console.log(presentFilter);
```

ES6

```js
var $scope = { presentOnColor: ['A', 'B', 'C'], presentOnStyle: ['B', 'C', 'D'], presentOnTechnique: ['B', 'C', 'F'] },
    presentFilter = [$scope.presentOnColor, $scope.presentOnStyle, $scope.presentOnTechnique]
        .reduce((a, b) => a.filter(c => b.includes(c)));

console.log(presentFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is very nicer more efficient way of solving the issue. I assumed A, B, C as the characters in he array. If this is happened to be the object give me properties of the object. If you get the idea then its okay.

```
// Given input as these 3 arrays

const presentOnColor = ['A', 'B', 'C']
const resentOnStyle = ['B', 'C', 'D'];
const presentOnTechnique = ['B', 'C', 'F'];

// Expected outcome
// const presentFilter = ['B', 'C'];

const arrayMap = [
    ...presentOnColor,
    ...resentOnStyle,
    ...presentOnTechnique
].reduce((object, item) => {
    object[item] = (object[item] || 0) + 1;
    return object;
}, {});

const presentFilter = Object.keys(arrayMap).filter(item => arrayMap[item] === 3);

console.log('presentFilter: ', presentFilter);
```